# How could I get the color of the surface to normal yellow for this surface plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

I am plotting a **yellow** surface using Python with `color='yellow'`, here is the codes that I wrote:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

#Below is the actual plot:
#============================================================================
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.arange(0,10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = -X**2-Y**2
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  color='yellow', alpha=.5)
```

However, what I obtained is a **yellow** surface looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFHSR.png),

which does not look very **yellow.**

The **yellow** color that I am intended to get for the surface should look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4we2Y.png), which could be easily obtained in 2d plots. However, it seems to me that I am unable to obtain this color in 3d surface plots.

Is there any way that I could obtain the **normal yellow** in the 3d plots? Many thanks  in advance for any help and advice!

Comment: It is semi transparent because of the alpha coefficient. Change its value and the more opaque you set it the more it will looks like the 2D example.

Comment: @jiandercy Thanks! But I don't think it's due to the alpha value, I think indeed they are two kinds of yellows.

Comment: Just trying to help. On 3D plot there are transparency, shadow and aliasing. Have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

#Below is the actual plot:
#============================================================================
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
x = np.arange(0,10,)
y = np.arange(0,10,)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = -X**2-Y**2
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,color='yellow', shade=False)
```

you can use **shade=False** and you will get a nice yellow color. Hope that helps

Comment: This method is so nice! I successfully got the yellow that I want to use. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the color string "yellow" in this line:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  color='yellow', alpha=.5)
```

with this:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  color='#fcfc03', alpha=.8)
```

Note the alpha value changed as well, which makes it less transparent but more 'yellow' visually. The alpha value affects how much you can see through it, so find a value that you like!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried to replace  color='yellow' with color='#fcfc03', but seems to still can't get the normal yellow for the surface. Is there any packages I should import to make this line work?